# aggregating values for bar plot

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

In R, I am attempting to make a `bar plot` that *aggregates* values from shared variables in a chart like so:

```
counts3 <- aggregate(x = data1$Annualized.Booking, by = list(data1$Country), FUN = sum)
barplot(counts3, main="Booking Distribution by Region",
    xlab="Regions", ylab="Annualized Bookings")
```

However, I am getting this error message:

[image: Error Message]

Which says that it is not a matrix, which I do not understand. For reference, this is what count3 looks like:

[image: sample of count3]

Is there an easier way of attempting to do this? Or is there a misunderstanding with what my matrix/vector is? Thank you.

Comment: You're trying to use `barplot` on a `data.frame` instead of a `matrix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to use `barplot` on a `data.frame`. Try a named vector or a matrix instead.

Example, with some sample data:

```
counts3 <- data.frame(Group.1 = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), x = c(10, 20, 5, 15))
```

Your error:

```
barplot(counts3, main = "Booking by Region", xlab = "Regions", ylab = "Value")
# Error in barplot.default(counts3, main = "Booking by Region", xlab = "Regions", :
#   'height' must be a vector or a matrix
```

Try this:

```
barplot(with(counts3, setNames(x, Group.1)), main = "Booking by Region",
        xlab = "Regions", ylab = "Value")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! Super helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`barplot` requires vectors as input, but `aggregate` returns a data frame. So you'd need to access the vectors explicitly when calling `barplot`. For example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(bookings = c(100, 200, 300, 100, 200, 300),
                    country = c("a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b"))

c3 <- aggregate(data1$bookings, list(data1$country), sum)

barplot(c3$x, names.arg = c3$Group.1)
```

It might be worthwhile to take a look at ggplot, that has a very expressive
grammar of graphics, e.g. it would do the aggregate step automatically. Working with the `data1` data frame defined above, this would produce the bar plot you are looking for:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = data1, aes(x = country, y = bookings)) + geom_col()
```

What's happening here is, that you first tell R that you want to do a ggplot with
`data1` as input data and that `country` should end up on the x-axis and `bookings` on the y axis. Then you simply add the type of visualization to the plot.